# Altbecon ranging stops detecting beacons after phone's bluetooth is turned off and back on

Tags: android, altbeacon

I'm using [Altbeacon](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) library to range bluetooth beacons and get TLM details

When I turn the phone's bluetooth off I stop seeing beacons as expected but as soon as I turn it back on I no longer see beacons although beacon scanner is still running

This is the configuration I'm using

```
        iBeaconManager.beaconParsers.add(
            BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT)
        )
        iBeaconManager.beaconParsers.add(
            BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT)
        )
        BeaconManager.setRegionExitPeriod(3000L)
        iBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers()
        iBeaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier)
        iBeaconManager.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0
        iBeaconManager.backgroundScanPeriod = 500
        iBeaconManager.foregroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0
        iBeaconManager.foregroundScanPeriod = 500
        iBeaconManager.startRangingBeacons(Region("eddystoneRegionName", Identifier.parse("0xD0F5A71096E300000000"), null, null))
```

I tried monitoring too and have the same result. I'm using a Moto G Power 2021 with Android 11.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is largely a consequence of a setting shown in the question:

`beaconManager.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0`

It probably also only happens if you set `beaconManager.eneableScheduledScanJobs =false` because otherwise scanning would be auto restarted every 15-25 mins.

The reason is that when the background between scan period is 0, scanning never stops and also never restarts.  If you turn off Bluetooth and turn it back on, that effectively kills the original scan.  And because the library was told to never stop that original scan, it never detects again.

Clearly, this is not intended library behavior, and it is fair to consider it a bug, given that the library does allow these non-default settings.  I will open this as an issue on the library GitHub repo.

In the meantime, you can work around this by doing one of two things:

1. Set the between scan period to something small like 100 ms.
2. Register for callbacks on Bluetooth state, and if it goes off, stop ranging, and if it starts again, restart ranging.